# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority using AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, x509, aws-iot

When trying to publish a message to a topic using the AWS IoT SDK for go I get the following error: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".
I am on windows and all I did was install different root CA's (literally via doubleclick) and a device certificate generated by AWS IoT Console.

I feel like I should somehow specify the path to the certificate but unlike the Python SDk the one for go does not mention that anywhere. I also added my credentials via the AWS Cli so that should not be the issue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/iotdataplane"
)

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-central-1"), Endpoint: aws.String("xxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    iotDataSvc := iotdataplane.New(sess)

    input := &iotdataplane.PublishInput{
        Payload: []byte(`{
            'state': {
             'desired':{
                    'humidity':10,
                    'temp':10
               }
            }
          }`),
        Topic: aws.String("/update"),
        Qos:   aws.Int64(0),
    }
    resp, err := iotDataSvc.Publish(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the mistake: xxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com needs to be xxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.